# Where should I be using a singleton and where should I be using a viewmodel for a 1 activity app?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm working on a single activity app in android and I'm conflicted on whether to use a viewmodel or a singleton. They seem to perform essentially the the same functions when it comes to single activity apps. Are there variables that are better to be stored in a singleton vs a viewmodel and vice versa?

Comment: [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [Singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/) both have different use cases, they are solutions to different problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about ViewModel class.

ViewModel : You actually WANT multiple instances (since each is going to vary) rather than a single instance that lives for the run of the application. ViewModels should not have a very long lifetime (another reason you don't want a singleton).  A singleton is unique for your entire process. A ViewModel is unique for a single Activity class (and, if you start multiple activities of that class, it is unique for each started activity)s.ViewModel's is mainly used for MVVM along with live data and implementing it is complex.

Singleton will be in memory as long as your application's context is valid.
A singleton is unique for your entire process.

Since, here in you know that you will always be having one activity, you can use singleton as its implementation is easy but for multiple activity application