# Is it Ok to use singleton instead of ViewModel in case of Jetpack Compose single activity app?

Tags: singleton, android-room, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

There is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617891/where-should-i-be-using-a-singleton-and-where-should-i-be-using-a-viewmodel-for), but I would like to ask specifically regarding Jetpack Compose. I have a single activity application that has a single ViewModel instance used in all composables. It works well, but now I need to add a Room db instance as a constructor parameter to it.

I've found a way via ViewModel Factory implementation in the Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-arch), but it looks a bit complicated compared to a singleton approach.

What actually is wrong with using a singleton instead of ViewModel for a single activity Compose app? It looks perfectly fine to have a singleton instance for the app lifetime. Why do we need to bother about the Activity lifecycle in this scenario? As a benefit I'll get rid of ViewModel dependency and most probably reduce apk size.